# Python FileNotFoundError when using open()

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I'm using `with open('myFile', 'rb') as file:` to read a file. When running the program with `python myProgram.py` everything works fine. But as soon I try to run it without `cd`-ing into the directory of `myProgram.py` and use an absolute path instead (like `python /home/myName/myCode/myProgram.py` I always get this error message: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

So why does `open()` behave differently depending on how the Python program is started? And is there a way to make things work even if starting with an absolute path?

I've already tried `open('/home/myName/myCode/myfile', 'rb')` but without success...

Comment: Are you sure the file is where you think it is?

Comment: run 'pwd' in the directory where you are able to run the program. post results.

Comment: you should provide your full traceback as well

Comment: The file is in the same directory as the python program.

WHen I run`pwd` in the directory where the program works it returns `/home/myName/myCode`. So that's exactly the directory where both my program and the file are.

Comment: The current working directory of a process and the directory that contains the script are not necessarily the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So why does open() behave differently depending on how the Python program is started? And is there a way to make things work even if starting with an absolute path?

Because that is standard behavior.  Not just for Python, but for all applications (at least all that I know of).  A relative path (like 'myfile') is assumed to be in the current directory.  That path will change depending on what directory you are sitting in when you launch the script from a shell.  If you don't give an absolute path, how would Python know which file to use in a directory structure like this?

```
root
|-- dir1
|   `-- myFile
`-- dir2
    `-- myFile
```

You were on the right track with `open('/home/myName/myCode/myfile', 'rb')`.

Comment: Thank you, this completely makes sense. I tried again with `open('/home/myName/myCode/myfile', 'rb')` and now it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you run `pwd` and it returns `/home/myName`. If you then run `/home/myName/code/myProgram.py`, the working directory of your program is *not* `/home/myName/code`; it's `/home/myName`. The working directory of a process in inherited from the parent process, not set based on where the script is located.